# PDF Merge throws warning and not merged the PDF using pdfbox-1.8.10.jar

Tags: pdfbox

I am using pdfbox1.8.10 and my folder has two documents, while merging I received the following warning and when I opened the merged PDF, it contains one PDF content and other PDF content ignored.
Please let me know your suggestions

```
Nov 23, 2015 8:41:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser parseCOSDictionary
WARNING: Invalid dictionary, found: 'f' but expected: '/'
Nov 23, 2015 8:41:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser parseCOSDictionary
WARNING: Invalid dictionary, found: '?' but expected: '/'
Nov 23, 2015 8:41:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.XrefTrailerResolver setStartxref
WARNING: Did not found XRef object at specified startxref position 0
Nov 23, 2015 8:41:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser parseCOSDictionary
WARNING: Invalid dictionary, found: 'f' but expected: '/'
```

Comment: Please share the pdfs

Comment: The PDF documents contains confidential information, so I can't share the PDF's

Comment: Then I can't help you. But most likely the PDF is corrupt. You could try to use the 2.0 RC2 version.